# Question mark folder

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp

I have read all of the other questions and websites about it. I cannot solve my problem.

I have had a problem with my Windows 7 bootcamp freezing. I force restarted a few times, and the last time it started a disk check (in windows 7 boot) and I didn't let it finish since I have like 1 billion files on it. It was at 5 percent for 2 hours and I just force restarted it.

Now I can't enter on the normal Macbook or Windows. I tried using the First Aid option a few times but it never worked.

Any help on this?

Comment: Recovery work?.

Comment: did you accidentally delete your operating system? the folder with a question mark means it cannot find an operating system...